# PySpark UDF optimization challenge

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am trying to optimize the code below. The when run with 1000 lines of data takes about 12 minutes to complete. Our use case would require data sizes to be around 25K - 50K rows which would make this implementation completely infeasible.

```
import pyspark.sql.types as Types
import numpy
import spacy
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

inputPath = "s3://myData/part-*.parquet"
df = spark.read.parquet(inputPath)

test_df = df.select('uid', 'content').limit(1000).repartition(10)

# print(df.rdd.getNumPartitions()) -> 4
# print(test_df.rdd.getNumPartitions()) -> 1

def load_glove(fn):
    vector_dict = {}
    count = 0
    with open(fn) as inf:
        for line in inf:
            count += 1
            eles = line.strip().split()
            token = eles[0]
            try:
                vector_dict[token] = numpy.array([float(x) for x in eles[1:]])
                assert len(vector_dict[token]) == 300
            except:
                print("Exception in load_glove")
                pass
    return vector_dict

# Returning an Array of doubles from the udf
@udf(returnType=Types.ArrayType(Types.FloatType()))
def generateVectorRepresentation(text):
  # TODO: move the load function out if posible, and remove unused modules 
  # nlp = spacy.load('en', disable=['parser', 'tagger'])
  nlp = spacy.load('en', max_length=6000000)
  gloveEmbeddingsPath = "/home/hadoop/short_glove_1000.300d.txt"
  glove_embeddings_dict = load_glove(gloveEmbeddingsPath)
  spacy_doc = nlp(text)
  doc_vec = numpy.array([0.0] * 300)
  doc_vec = numpy.float32(doc_vec)
  wordcount = 0
  for sentence_id, sentence in enumerate(spacy_doc.sents):
      for word in sentence:
          if word.text in glove_embeddings_dict:
              # Pre-convert to glove dictionary to float32 representations
              doc_vec += numpy.float32(glove_embeddings_dict[word.text])
              wordcount += 1

  # Document Vector is the average of all word vectors in the document
  doc_vec = doc_vec/(1.0 * wordcount)
  return doc_vec.tolist()

spark.udf.register("generateVectorRepresentation", generateVectorRepresentation)

document_vector_df = test_df.withColumn("Glove Document Vector", generateVectorRepresentation('content'))

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")
pandas_document_vector_df = document_vector_df.toPandas()

# print(pandas_document_vector_df)
pandas_document_vector_df.head()
```

I was wondering if you guys could help answer the questions below

Is the spacy.load() and load_glove() method invoked on every iteration?
Is there a way to prepare the load_glove() data once for every worker node instead of once for every line of data?
The load_glove method returns a dictionary object which could be as large as 5GB. Is there a way to prepare that on the master node and then pass as a parameter to the UDF?

Appreciate your suggestions. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in the current implementation, all the model-loading code would be executed each time your function is run, which is far from optimal. There's no way to pass it from driver to worker nodes directly, but there's a similar way - initialize model on each worker, but only once. For that, you'll have to use lazy function, that will be executed only when the actual result would be required - so, on workers.

Try doing something like this:

```py
# Here we are not loading the model at the loading time, only the worker code
# will invoke this routine and gets the spacy object. Which means we are loading
# new spacy models on every executors.
SPACY_MODEL = None
def get_spacy_model():
    global SPACY_MODEL
    if not SPACY_MODEL:
       _model = spacy.load('en', max_length=6000000)
    SPACY_MODEL = _model
    return SPACY_MODEL

@udf(returnType=Types.ArrayType(Types.FloatType()))
def generateVectorRepresentation(text):
  # TODO: move the load function out if posible, and remove unused modules 
  # nlp = spacy.load('en', disable=['parser', 'tagger'])
  nlp = get_spacy_model()
  # your further processing
```

I think you can try adding glove loading code into a similar function.

You can try reading more about that here: https://haridas.in/run-spacy-jobs-on-apache-spark.html (this is not my blog, just found this info while trying to do same thing you need with Spacy model).

Comment: Rai Thanks a lot for the response, this worked both for loading the spacy model and the glove dictionary. It led to huge performance gains! Appreciate your response. One minor correction to the above mode is that the SPACY_MODEL = _model line needs to be inside the if statement.

Comment: I tried to replicate with another similar nlp pipeline from a different library, but I ran into this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65565976/pyspark-string-syntax-error-on-udf-that-returns-maptypestringtype-stringtype Could it be causing race conditions when the UDF is run in parallel?

Comment: You can load the model and then broadcast it. Then access the broadcasted value in the udf. Here's an example.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77033826/3238085

Answer (score 0):

The main thing that makes udf-s so slow is that they cannot be optimized by spark (they are treated like a black box). So to make it faster you need to take out as much as you can and substitute it with vanilla spark functions. The ideal thing to do would be to only leave the `spacy` part (I am not familiar with that module) in the udf, get a resulting DF, and do the rest of the transformations needed with vanilla spark functions.

For example `load_glove()` will be executed for every row as the other answer says. But looking at the code, its format looks like it can be turned into a dataframe with 301 columns. Then you can do join on that to get needed values. (if you can get the other DF to have `word.text` as keys, it's a bit hard to tell without the data, but it looks possible in theory).

Comment: thanks for your response. yes, I am exploring that way as well.